# choosing and selecting from divs

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have 2 divs like this belonging to different teams. All of them has different names and ids

```html
<div id="joinville">
  <div class="gk">
    <div id="john">
      <img src:xxx ">
                                <h6 class="namejoinville ">John</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div id="jake ">
                                <img src:xxx">
      <h6 class="namejoinville">Jake</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="allan">
      <img src:xxx ">
                                <h6 class="namejoinville ">Allan</h6>
                            </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    
    <div id="thunder ">    
           <div class="gk ">
                            <div id="amilcar ">
                                <img src:xxx">
      <h6 class="namethunder">Amilcar</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="peter">
      <img src:xxx ">
                                <h6 class="namethunder ">Peter</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div id="jm ">
                                <img src:xxx">
      <h6 class="namethunder">James</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Them I have this:

```
<div id="onethree">
                        <div id="grteam">
                            <img src="xxx"">
                            <h6 id="j1">GK</h6>
                        </div>
```

I want to whenever I click on one of the player to change the "grteam" div to the one selected.

How can i make this with js?
Sorry, if this is basic stuff but i'm still a begginner

Comment: Note, within the Document Object Model (DOM) id’s MUST be unique. Which “Joinville” is which?

Comment: Sorry, i was copying and wrote it wrong. I just edit to the right one

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the one selected"? What should happen to the grteam?

Comment: `<img src:xxx">` ??

Comment: The grteam should be replace from the one selected. For example, if i click on <div id="amilcar">, the grteam should be replace by that div.

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the player name his data moves to `#grteam`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.gk div h6').forEach(player => {
    player.addEventListener('click', updateSelectedPlayer, this);
});

function updateSelectedPlayer(player) {
    let greatPlayerImg = document.querySelector('#grteam>img'),
        greatPlayerName = document.querySelector('#grteam>h6'),
        selectedPlayerImg = player.target.parentNode.querySelector('img').src,
        selectedPlayerName = player.target.innerHTML;

        greatPlayerImg.src = selectedPlayerImg;
        greatPlayerName.innerHTML = selectedPlayerName;
}
```

```html
    <div id=Joinville>`    
        <div class="gk">
                         <div id="john">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namejoinville">John</h6>
                         </div>
                         <div id="jake">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namejoinville">Jake</h6>
                         </div>
                         <div id="allan">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namejoinville">Allan</h6>
                         </div>
           </div>
     </div>
 
 <div id=Joinville>`    
        <div class="gk">
                         <div id="amilcar">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namethunder">Amilcar</h6>
                         </div>
                         <div id="peter">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namethunder">Peter</h6>
                         </div>
                         <div id="jm">
                             <img src='xxx'>
                             <h6 class="namethunder">James</h6>
                         </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     
     <div id="onethree">
        <div id="grteam">
            <img src="xxx">
            <h6 id="j1">GK</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked as a charm! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: happy to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

I suggest as a beginner that you get used to using common class names for similar elements

Here I have two `class="team"` and each team has a group of `class="player"` and each player has an inner `class="player-name"`

Note that the id on player elements is irrelevant this way

You can add other classes as well but this helps styling the structure and makes the javascript simpler to traverse these common items

Working example without the images. You can extend this to work with those yourself

```js
const players = document.querySelectorAll('.player')

players.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // name of selected player
    const name = el.querySelector('.player-name').textContent;
    // add selected name to grteam
    document.querySelector('#j1').textContent = name;
    // remove active class from players
    players.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('active')
    })
    // add active class to selected player
    el.classList.add('active')
  })

})
```

```css
#container{display:flex}
.team{flex-basis:50%;padding:.5em}
h6{ font-size: 1em; margin:0}
.player{ border:2px solid #ccc; padding:.5em; margin-bottom:1em}
.player.active{border-color:red}
```

```html
<div id="grteam">
  Active: <strong id="j1">None</strong>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="team">
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">John</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">Jake</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">Allan</h6>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="team">
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">Amilcar</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">Peter</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="player">
      <h6 class="player-name">James</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```